# Git - Borrar archivos con rm (no con "git rm") y reflejarlo en el index, el repositorio local y el repositorio remoto

Tags: git

Hace unos días comencé a estudiar Git. He comprendido todo bastante bien, aunque tengo algunas dudas respecto a cómo borrar archivos.

Precisamente, lo que quiero saber es cómo borro un archivo/directorio con el comando "`rm`" de linux y que ésta acción no sólo se vea reflejada en el index (`stage`), sino también en el repositorio local y en el repositorio remoto.

Tengo entendido que si borro un archivo/directorio y le doy seguimiento con el comando "git add", dicho cambio se reflejará en el index (`stage`), pero no en el repositorio local (`git commit`) ni en el repositorio remoto (`git push`). Sin embargo, cuando borro un archivo con el comando "`rm`" de linux y lo añado al index (stage) y posteriormente ejecuto los comando "`git commit`" y "`git push`", los archivos eliminados también desaparecen del repositorio local y del repositorio remoto.

¿Es necesario utilizar el comando "`rm`" de Git o puedo utilizar el comando "`rm`" de linux (más cómodo para mi) y reflejar de alguna manera tal acción, no sólo en el index (`stage`), sino también en el repositorio local y en el repositorio remoto?

Gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si utilizas sólo `rm` tienes que hacer un `git add <ficha_a_eliminar>`, con `git rm <ficha_a_eliminar>` te lo hace todo en un solo paso.

> Otra cosa que puede que quieras hacer es mantener el archivo en tu
>   directorio de trabajo, pero eliminarlo de tu área de preparación.
>   Dicho de otro modo, puede que quieras mantener el archivo en tu disco
>   duro, pero interrumpir su seguimiento por parte de Git. Esto resulta
>   particularmente útil cuando olvidaste añadir algo a tu archivo
>   `.gitignore` y lo añadiste accidentalmente, como un archivo de log
>   enorme, o un montón de archivos.
>
> Para hacer esto, usa la opción
>   `--cached`:

```
git rm --cached <ficha_a_eliminar>
```

[`+ Info`](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Guardando-cambios-en-el-repositorio)

Comment: Excelente, éso es lo que necesitaba saber. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Los cambios primero se realizan en tu repositorio local, cuando haces `push` haces cambios en el repositorio remoto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**para agregar localmente un archivo/s en git es:**

```
git add 'archivoSeleccionado'
```

terminas de agregar localmente debes hacer 'commit'

```
git commit -m 'nuevo commit'
```

> para hacer cambios al repositorio remoto se debe hacer push

```
git push origin 'nombreDeTuRama'
```

**para eliminar localmente un archivo/s en git es:**

```
git rm 'archivoSeleccionado'
```

o si quieres eliminar carpetas usas rm -r

```
git rm -r 'carpetaSeleccionado'
```

terminas de agregar localmente debes hacer 'commit'

```
git commit -m 'nuevo commit'
```

> para hacer cambios al repositorio remoto de debe hacer push

```
git push origin 'nombreDeTuRama'
```